# UI Editor for .NET application

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, user-interface

I need .NET UI control that acts as a designer/editor window similar to what you see in some of these applications:
 - Visual Studio 
 - Visio 
 - Balsamiq 
 - Windows Workflow 
 - Photoshop

I hope to use WPF, but will settle for WinForms. I need to create custom widgets that I can drag, drop, and edit in the designer/editor window.  I am open to building or buying.

After looking at the common third-party .NET tool providers I cannot find anything.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would tend to go with WPF and rolling my own implementation. In WPF it is comparably easy to build wyswig style editors  because you can host anything within anything (e.g. a Button within a drawing) and you can quickly reuse the rendered bitmap of a control or drawing in several palces of your UI (think preview pane etc.) without any perfomance penalty ([VisualBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.aspx)). I wrote a small editor once myself and made heavy use of [adorners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx) - I didn't find it too hard.

Answer (score 2):

You can start with [this](http://www.divil.co.uk/net/articles/designers/hosting.asp) (Hosting Windows Forms Designers), it pretty much implements everything needed to create a WinForm designer.

[Hosting Windows Forms Designers http://img141.imageshack.us/img141/8755/winformhost.png](http://img141.imageshack.us/img141/8755/winformhost.png)